# How to add a custom filter using Java in Logback

Tags: logging, logback

I have designed a filter, CustomFilter. Now in logback.xml we add
`<filter class="in.firestart.myCompany.logging.CustomLevelFilter" />` 
Now i want to do this at run time. How can i achieve this is in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

`in.myCompany.logging.CustomLevelFilter filterObj = new in.myCompany.logging.CustomLevelFilter();
filterObj.start();
newFileAppender.addFilter(filterObj);`

Found the Answer. Create an object of your filter and pass it as a parameter to the addFilter method of appender